# StackExchange clone using WordPress?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, clone-site

If you were to build a StackExchange clone site using WordPress, how would you do it?

Comment: I would use PHP code to do that and make use of a database, most certainly MySQL as it already come with wordpress.

Comment: If you are done, be sure to add it to [the list of SO clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953). Or use one of them, and enjoy the time you saved.

Comment: Where did I mention I would do it from scratch? ;)

Comment: Fitting post on topic of cloning SE [Code: It's Trivial](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/code-its-trivial.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using WordPress as a CMS (content management system), this would be relatively straight-forward.  Just remember, straight-forward **does not** mean "easy" ...

## Custom Post Types

One of the newest and best features of WordPress is custom post types.  Rather than using a traditional post or page, I would make two kinds of custom post types - one for questions and one for answers.  Obviously the question will have titles, tags, and content.  The answers will just have content.

I'd also add a custom meta value to each answer to tie it to a specific question.

Both questions and answers can have comments, which works well with the existing framework

## Voting

There are several different voting plug-ins available, though none really handles the meritocracy system that SO has built up.  Still, any plug-in that allows you to rate a question/answer will be a good place to start.  With some minor tweaking you could get it working like the up/down voting system of SO.

## Meritocracy

Each user account would have to have a custom field associated with the user's reputation.  This would be modified directly by the up/down vote plug-in.

## Other features

The rest of the UI would be entirely up to you - it could either mirror SO completely or take on its own format.  Really, once you have questions and answers presented and persisted in the database correctly, the sky's the limit.